# How to switch from starter to premium Here SDK for android

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I was using Here sdk but i decided going for premium SDK I did all the necessary steps i.e License Key,App Code,App Id ,replacing starter with premium .aar file ,checking the package name (if its different),adding dependencies in gradle and when i tried using some class i.e **CoreRouter** or **AroundRequest** i am unable to call the class. I checked all the steps for the setup of SDK's I didn't missed any. Did anyone got similar issue like this one?

Update:

I created new project and started working on it but when I implemented some class of here sdk's it throws error while compiling :

**- cannot find symbol class

- package doesn't exist
- incompatibility types**

in Document it is said to use these classes yet they are not present in sdk Did anyone faced this issue?

**Refer the screenshot for errors**:

[image: refer the screenshot for errors]

**Refer the Screenshot there is no class present of CoreRouter,RouterWaypoint,Routing error**:

[image: Refer the Screenshot there is no class present of CoreRouter,RouterWaypoint,Routing error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what was the problem yet.One solution fixed the issue ... what i did was deleted the .aar file from project libs file, removed Here dependencies lastly rebuild the project. Now i again pasted the .aar file added the here dependencies and did project rebuild and clean project.Then it started working all classes were imported successfuly, it was a suprise for me tho..Hope this resolution helps for someone who got similar problem. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the right sdk. One way to check if your sdk supports the classes you require is to open /sdk/HERE-sdk/libs/docs/mapsdoc-hybridplus/index.html and search for your class. If it is available then definitely you should be able to use it. Check your gradle properties to see if you included the Here-sdk like below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['HERE-sdk.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```